# Getting data from sql and xml field Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Running a sql query results in a table like following where column NTLdata is of xml file.

```
ID     Status     NTLdata        PLPData    

2365   Active    <com.123.ser..  <com.abc...
4962   Active    <com.123.req..  <com.abc...
899    Active    <com.123.ser..  <com.abc...
```

I'm validating a node value from the xml files like this-

```
$SqlConn= New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConn.ConnectionString= "Server= $server; Database=$DB"
$SqlConn.open()
$SqlCmd= New-Object New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText =$query
$SqlCmd.Connection=$SqlConn
$SqlAdapter= New-Object New-Object System.Data.SqlClient..SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand=$SqlCmd
$Dataset= New-Object.System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapte.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null
$table= $DataSet.Tables[0]
$SqlConn.Close()
# retreieving xml column
$xmlCol= $table | %{ [xml]$_.NTLdata } #this has all the rows of NTLData as xml files type
$data= $xmlCol.SelectNodes("//Edition" | ? {$_.InnerText -eq '22'} 
# data has the <Edition> where value is 22
if ($data -ne $null) {
# *print the id from the column ID*
}
```

Here I want to get the xml files of all rows of the NTLdata column in which the  value is 22. For those records, I need to get the corresponding id from the sql query returned table. How to achieve this?

example xml file

```
<com.123.req.abc.xyz>
<CheckPoint>
  <Number>025364</Number>
  <Cost>3333</Cost>
</CheckPoint>
<item>
  <code>18##</code>
  <Edition>22</Edition>
</item>
</com.123.req.abc.xyz>
```

Assuming this file is from the 2nd row of the example table then I want the `id 4962` to be displayed. I'm stuck and out of ideas !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, which outputs the IDs of those table rows where the `.NTLdata` field contains XML with an `Edition` element whose inner text is `'22'`:

```
$table |
  Where-Object { ([xml] $_.NTLdata).SelectSingleNode('//Edition[.=22]') } |
    ForEach-Object Id
```